# How do you correctly say large numbers

Tags: numbers

I saw a post on [The daily What](http://thedailywh.at/2011/08/14/lights-out-137/) which links to a video where a person [counts from 1 to 100,000](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQBH-LhJuOc).

Is he saying a large portion of the numbers wrong?

Back in high school my algebra teacher was extremely picky.  If we were going to say the number 135, we would say one hundred thirty-five.  If a person said one hundred and thirty-five my teacher would interpret that to mean 100.35.  Was my algebra teacher wrong, or did Jon just waste over 80 hours counting to 100,000 incorrectly.

I tried searching the web, but searching for ‘numbers and’  doesn’t work very well.  Can you point me to a reference or style guide that describes how to properly say large numbers?

Comment: How do you say 25, five and twenty or twenty five?

Comment: @Pratik In Standard English it is twenty five, in old British (Scottish?) English it was five and twenty.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker Exactly. My point was how you say numbers depends on many things like culture, background, upbringing etc.

Comment: I don't understand your teacher. 100.35 is definitely not pronounced "one hundred and thirty five".

Comment: "One hundred point thirty-five" = 103.5; 100.35 = "one hundred point three five". My maths teacher was punctilious about that.

Comment: And how did you teacher say 135.35? "One hundred thirty-five and thirty-five?" The only thing I can think of in UK English which would approximate 'and as point' would be old-style money ("six and ten" = 6s10d)

Comment: Ooops, make that [ten and six](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/LewisCaroll-AliceInWonderland/pages/alice_11b/) :)

Comment: @TRiG I would *never* interpret "One hundred point thirty-five" as 103.5

Comment: Usage of "and" is regional!  This happens quit a bit on EL&U: Declaring something "wrong" when it is perfectly correct on the other side of the Atlantic.  Or even just elsewhere on the same island.

Comment: 100.35 = "One hundred and thirty-five hundredths" if you were being pedantic or scientific about the English phrasing of such a number. In conversation it would be "One hundred point three five." In the case of the former, the word "and" is used to establish the decimal place.

Comment: @JYelton: In your first example, "and" doesn't establish the decimal place, "hundredths" does (though you probably can't put the "and" anywhere else and still make sense).

Comment: @John: To my ear, "and" serves to tell the listener that there is to be an addendum. I've always been taught that to say "one hundred and thirty-five" for 135 is incorrect. In this case "and" means an addendum of a decimal or partial. *Hundredths* establishes the number of places, just as *thousandths* would. To omit "and" would be awkward indeed: "One hundred thirty-five hundredths." 1.35?

Comment: @TRiG, I'm sorry, but you also had a weird teacher :( could you find a citation for that, since I think it's just wrong. And I have just tested Microsoft Speech Recognition and Dragon Dictation and both render "one hundred point thirty-five" as `100.35`.

Comment: @JYelton: "One hundred and thirty-five" versus "One hundred thirty-five" (for 135) clearly varies, as the range of responses shows (I thought it was just a British/American difference, but it may be even more complex than that). I agree that "One hundred (and) thirty-five hundredths" sounds silly without the "and". My only disagreement was with your original statement "In the case of the former, the word "and" is used to establish the decimal place.", where in fact the use of "hundredths" clearly makes the decimal place explicit.

Comment: By the way, essentially the same question has been asked at least once before: [english.stackexchange.com/questions/17540/reading-out-numbers-in-english](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17540/reading-out-numbers-in-english) (and if I remember right, more often).  But given how many interesting answers and comments this has garnered, there was clearly space for it to be asked again!

Answer (score 26):

"One hundred and thirty-five" is perfectly correct, although the "and" tends to be removed in American English. It makes sense mathematically, since "and" is synonymous with "plus" — two apples and three apples makes five apples. One hundred, and thirty-five, makes 135.

The "and" is particularly useful when articulating a series of numbers. "One hundred one, one hundred two" could easily be misheard as "one hundred, one, one hundred, two" whereas using "one hundred and one, one hundred and two" removes that ambiguity.

Ultimately though it depends on location and culture. In the UK the "and" is always used; in the US there are a mixture of usages.

Looking at this ngram, it seems that skipping the "and" has only gained popularity over the last hundred years or so but using the "and" is still far more prevalent:
[image: Relative popularity of "one hundred one" versus "one hundred and one"]

Comment: That is not the question; the question is - from ngrams, is the blue line supposed to mean 101 or 100.1? (same for red)

Comment: I agree with the "and" usage. I am not a native speaker, but for what it's worth, I use it.

Comment: @Unreason I beg to differ. The question was, if a person includes the "and", (and I quote), "Is he saying a large portion of the numbers wrong?" The supposed alternative meaning of "one hundred and thirty five" being interpreted as 100.35 is a side issue.

Comment: @Waggers, let's leave it to the OP to clarify - to me what you call a side issue is exactly what is referred to in the quote "Is he saying...wrong?"

Comment: One hundred and thirty-five **never** means 100.35. Nor does one hundred thirty-five.

Comment: "The "and" is particularly useful when articulating a series of numbers." - so, what about "thirty-five" vs "thirty, five"?

Comment: @Random832 Good point! It was just an idea :) Perhaps we should adopt the German system where it would be "five and thirty" - but perhaps not...

Comment: @Random832 - It is usually obvious from the cadence of the sentence, *"thirty" pause "five"* would be two numbers, and is more than enough to differentiate it from *"thirty" no pause "five"* which would be a single number.

Comment: Even if we do assume *and* to mean *plus*, then in a [positional numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) *one hundred and thirty-five* would be interpreted as 100 + 35, or 135.

Comment: Unfortunately the graph doesn't proove anything, as +Unreason points out: this graph can perfectly show that "101" is losing popularity and that "100.01" (cent) is gaining popularity.

Answer (score 15):

Your algebra teacher, if s/he ever in fact claimed that, is wrong. While it's common [at least for math teachers] to say that "and" must not be used *except* to separate the integer part from the fraction/decimal part, the usage is "One hundred and thirty-five hundredths" for 100.35, and the "hundredths" is *not* optional. This rule makes "One hundred and thirty-five [stop]" *meaningless*; it does not assign it a meaning of "100.35".

Comment: As I've remarked in another question, I find it hard to imagine a British person saying "and thirty-five hundredths" in any context. We just don't turn decimals into fractions in that way.

Comment: Neither do Americans, except for math teachers.

Comment: You can use "cents" instead of "hundredths". Can't you?

Comment: @djeidot: "One hundred and thirty-five cents" would mean "135 cents" (unless you're using "hundred" to mean "$100 bill").

Answer (score 10):

I've never heard the digits following the decimal point to be pronounced like the questioner describes. It's always "something-point-three-five". The digits to the right of the decimal point are named individually. I've worked a lot with accountants and statisticians.

Answer (score 8):

American math text books and math manuals (e.g.: Math At Hand published by Great Source Publications) tell students that they don't say 'and' as they are speaking a number.

From page 5 of that text: 
How would you read 905,346,521?
Say: nine hundred five million, three hundred forty-six thousand, five hundred twenty-one.

That is an **American** text.

As a British person, I find this cumbersome and I am sorry, but very American.

I now live in Canada and a teacher told me recently that 120 must be pronounced 'one hundred twenty', because if children say 'one hundred and twenty' then it means one hundred POINT 20.

Of course I said that it does not. In fact, either with the 'and' or without is acceptable, but 'and' does not mean 'point'. The teacher tried to tell me that it did. 
This is worrying for what is going to go down the line in our kids' education and declining numeracy abilities. Additionally, we don't say 'twenty' after the decimal point, we say 'point two zero', or better yet, 'point two'. You can put as many zeroes as you like after a decimal digit with a value and it doesn't change its value. 0.1 is the same as 0.1000000. So don't bother with the extra zeroes.

American math manuals and teachers seem to want to express the decimal fraction in terms of relating it to the place value chart, so a decimal part is named so many tenths or hundredths or thousandths or ten thousandths or hundred thousandths or millionths. Really? It **is** essential to understand the place value chart, but if you express a decimal number as a fraction you are going to get a bunch of kids stopping in their tracks in confusion. I looked on the web this morning and there are some people actually saying that 1.2000 is 'one and two thousandths'. Really? Why not bung in another few zeroes and decide to call it 2 millionths instead? I kid you not. People, if you're going to teach it, you'd better understand it.

I believe it is acceptable to choose to say 'and' or not in your expression of numbers - either is fine but as a British person I always say 'and' when speaking a number such as 1,256. However a decimal point must ALWAYS be clearly stated as either 'point' or you could say 'decimal'. Anything else will cause confusion. Following a decimal point, each digit is to be read individually: 1.234 is said aloud as 'one point two three four'.
It leaves no room for ambiguity or mistake. Bottom line.

If a student is given a mixed number or mixed fraction (same thing, slightly different name) such as 57 20/100 (fifty seven and twenty hundredths) then you say it as a fraction, using 'and', as I just wrote it in words. 
However, when you transform that fraction into a decimal number kids should first reduce it (so they can comprehend it better) and  twenty hundredths is actually the same as two tenths, so the number becomes 57.2
Knowing the place value, you know that the first column after the decimal point is tenths, the second column is hundredths the third column is thousandths. If you have two hundredths, the two belongs in the hundredths column (col. 2), but two tenths, the 2 belongs in the first column.

There is lots of room for confusion if you don't know what you are doing, and trying to tell kids that 'and' means 'decimal point' is one big fat way of adding further to the confusion they are going to have. Teachers: please don't do that.

Answer (score 7):

Here are a couple more charts. Firstly, to show even Americans still use **and** more often than not...
[image]

And secondly, to show that Brits remain impervious to such pedantry...
[image]

Personally I think it's potty to rant about one or the other being more "correct", and it's positively disturbing to see people thinking this leaves scope for confusion between 120 and 100.20. I don't know who thought up dropping the "and" (though Noah Webster has "form" on such issues), but I'm sure they'd be aghast to find it's apparently led to *more* misunderstandings, not less.

TL;DR: Go with the usage you were taught, but please don't assume others are wrong.

On behalf of the Brits and Walt Disney, I must just say I never heard even an American refer to [One Hundred One Dalmatians.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Hundred_and_One_Dalmatians)

Answer (score 6):

Depends on your background but, in Greek speak (at least), the word "and" is used to describe decimal places.  So one hundred "and" thirty five means 100.35, unlike one hundred thirty five, which means 135.  In English speak, however, the word "and" is not used to describe decimal places.  The word "point" is used instead.  Thus, one hundred "and" thirty five becomes 135, while one hundred "point" thirty five is 100.35.

Comment: ...and "dot" is often used in place of "point" lately (I noticed it became common in the late 1990s after the internet started gaining popularity, mostly thanks to _www-dot_ and _dot-COM_).

Comment: @Randolf - How true!!!  I should have known, as I am a computer nerd....LOL

Comment: "One hundred point thirty five" runs into the same problem as using "and" in English speaking countries where the radix symbol is a comma.

Comment: @oosterwal Which countries would those be, exactly?

Comment: @Random832: South Africa?

Answer (score 3):

"One hundred and thirty five" should definitely be interpreted as 135, not 100.35. "One hundred thirty five" is more acceptable in the U.S., especially in technical settings, although the former is also frequently used. Leaving out the "and" has the advantage of being less ambiguous, in the sense that "one hundred and thirty five" could mean "135" or "100, 35".

Answer (score 2):

- If you accept Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101_(number) is pronounced "one hundred and one", "a hundred and one", "one hundred one", "a hundred one", or "one oh one".
- [WebMath](http://www.webmath.com/saynum.html) and [Wolfram](http://wolframalpha.com) both writes "one hundred one"
- [WebMath](http://www.webmath.com/saynum.html) says 100.01 is one hundred and one hundredth

Answer (score -1):

I was taught (and it seems logical to me) that 100.35 is read " one-hundred point three five,"
135 is read "one-hundred thirty-five" and to say "one-hundred and thirty-five" should be left for instances where you are speaking of two distinct numbers: 100, and 35

Answer (score -1):

In American English, 135 is pronounced *one-hundred thirty-five*. 100.35 would be pronounced *one-hundred and 35 hundredths*.

Comment: That seems to be the case only in American English. In the UK, 135 would be pronounced as *one hundred and thirty five*. 100.35 would be pronounced as *one hundred point thirty five*.

Comment: @Tristan Yes. Hence I stated, "In American English" at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: I’ve lived in America all my life (quite a few years), and if I heard “one-hundred and 35 hundredths”, I would say, “Wait. What?” I may have heard that a few times in my life, but, as far as I can recall, not since I’ve been in school.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  P.S. How do you think we pronounce a hyphen?  Since you’re talking about **pronunciation**, why don’t you just say, “In American English, 135 is pronounced *one hundred thirty five*.” (without the hyphens)?

Answer (score -3):

I'm a first grade teacher and I teach my students to leave out the 'and' because I am a former bookkeeper and when working with money one hundred and thirty five is one hundred dollars and thirty-five cents. Please teach it the correct way !!

Comment: What is correct, seems to depend on whether someone speaks American English, or not.

Comment: How would you say, $135.35? One hundred thirty-five and thirty-five. Or one hundred and thirty-five dollars and thirty-five cents.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Interestingly, I’d say neither—I’d say “one hundred and thirty-five thirty-five”, just like I’d say something costs “nineteen ninety-nine” or “thirty-four ninety-five”. With money, the usage of _and_ seems to be **precisely the opposite** of what the asker’s math teacher and user57131 are advocating.

Comment: And I'd just say "One thirty-five thirty-five" to mean 135.35.

Answer (score -5):

Saying and in a number is a huge pet peeve of mine. I despise it. Lazy and incorrect.  One hundred and one dalmations. Not one hundred and one dalmations. It's sloppy to add an "and" in there. Takes more time it's the matgh equivalent to "um". Slang.

Comment: 1) This is a Q&A site, not a forum to air your peeves. 2) Your ‘correct’ and ‘wrong’ Disney titles are the same. 3) It’s neither. Whether or not you include _and_, the dogs in question are **dalmatians**, not *dalmations. 4) ‘Sloppy’ or ‘lazy’ would be leaving something out (like the punctuation missing in your last sentence). Adding an entire extra word to a phrase can never be considered ‘sloppy’ or ‘lazy’. 5) Read the other answers to see why including _and_ is **not** ‘incorrect’. You’re free not to like it, but it’s not ‘incorrect’. 6) _Um_ is not slang.

Comment: ... and spelling "math" with a "g" is sloppy.

Answer (score -8):

Although it depends a little on you background / culture / origin etc. According to **Standard English** , your teacher was right.

Although calling 135 :

> One hundred and thirty five

is very widely done, it is **incorrect**. Whereas saying

> One hundred thirty five

is obscure and causes confusions, it is *grammatically* **correct**. (Though I do feel sorry for the guy who counted from 1 to 100,000.)

[Although I am not sure whether `One hundred _and_ thirty five` should be interpreted as 100.35]

There are many style guides that explain . Here are some links:

[1-How to write numbers with words.](http://www.ehow.com/how_4715601_write-numbers-words.html)

[2-Ten rules for writing numbers with numerals.](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/10-rules-for-writing-numbers-and-numerals/)

[3-Number to Word converter.](http://www.easysurf.cc/cnvert18.htm)

[4-Ten Rules for writing numbers](http://www.grammarbook.com/numbers/numbers.asp)

[5-Writing Numbers (another converter)](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/texte/ausschreiben.htm)

Comment: What is "Standard English"?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: So, we can't say "one hundred and thirty five" or "one hundred thirty five"... How do you say the number 135 then?

Comment: @Alenanno Your choice. Either choose the incorrect yet popular way, or choose the obscure yet correct way.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: What I meant is that you "criticised" both ways, but you didn't proposed an alternate one, unless I missed it in your answer.

Comment: @Alenanno Well, my approach was to tell the Pros and Cons of both ways. I guess you are sort of right, I did criticise both ways, but  I needed to explain the situation to the OP.

Comment: I'm not sure how you square this assertion with Waggers' answer. And I'm sorry, but (from your first link) *"Everybody does (...)  but it's not correct."* is like finger nails on a blackboard to my descriptivist ears.

Comment: -1: invoking 'Standard English' is not very helpful! What 'Standard' are you referring to? Why should the popular way be 'incorrect'? What authority do any of your links have?

Comment: Ignoring issues with the term "Standard English", a number of the references cited do indicate that the correct language for 135 is "one hundred thirty five" (i.e. omits the “and”).