# "Three-hundred forty-two" or "three-hundred and forty-two"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, conjunctions, numbers

So on this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699791/finding-the-word-version-of-a-number/12700097#comment17146082_12700097

We were having the argument whether it is “three hundred *and* forty two” or “three hundred forty two”.

I am going by British and New Zealand grammar and I believe it has the *and* in there. I have never in my life heard anyone say “three hundred forty two”, only “three hundred and forty two”.

So when it comes to numbers, what’s the rule?

Comment: So...US just wants to be different?

Comment: In the US, I was taught that you use *and* when there's a decimal: 13.5 = "thirteen *and* a half" or 1.3 = "one *and* a third" or 1,345.257 = "one thousand three-hundred forty-five *and* two-hundred fifty-seven thousandths".

Comment: `forty-two` then...

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://english.stackexchange.com/a/38032/9368

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading out numbers in English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17540/reading-out-numbers-in-english)

Comment: "Three hundred and forty two" is what people say in Britain, Australia and New Zealand.  The OED has examples demonstrating this, so I don't know why anyone would assert that this is not correct.  Maybe tchrists's comment above should be amended to read _in no country called the United States of America is "three hundred and forty two" ever correct_.

Comment: @David: I think tchrist means it is incorrect to omit the hyphen in 'forty-two'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that is the correct usage in British English:

http://www.usingenglish.com/files/pdf/big-numbers-american-and-british-english.pdf

In American English, the use of the *and* is uncommon for use in the integer portion of the number (I was specifically taught not to use it):

http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/saying_large_numbers01.html

I was also taught to use *and* between the integer part and the portion to the right of the decimal point which is spoken as a fraction (two tenths, forty-five hundredths, etc.):

http://www.basic-mathematics.com/writing-decimals-in-words.html

Comment: _Three hundred forty-two_ for American English. I always have to delete the _and_ in Taiwanese Chinese-English, & I often have to add the hyphen between _forty_ and _two_. Historically, of course, many Americans wanted to be different: specifically, they wanted to be independent & sovereign rather than ruled by the king of England. But almost all the differences between the Anglophone countries evolved for a variety of reasons that have little or nothing to do with a narcissistic desire to be unique or even **very** unique. But ethnocentrism's a normal human bias & not worth a temper tantrum.

Comment: To my ear, "and" would not sound correct with a voiced "d", nor following a voice "d" on "hundred" or "thousand", but when more numbers follow "hundred" the "d" is stifled such that it sounds a bit like "nd".